# Some very (very) strange issues in wpa handshake

Tags: authentication

I have a router (actually it is an android phone as an access point) with wpa2 AES encription, and I'm trying to crack the password with a very small word list.

Strangest thing is, when I use wireshark with EAPOL filter, and deauth, I actually can see the 4 way handshake, but aircrack still says "no valid handshake"

Any ideas?...

Comment: using aircrack on the 'monitor'?

Comment: Are you running wirrshark on the same nic as aircrack?